# Texmaker build problem. Can't generate new pdf

Tags: texmaker

I have installed `texmaker` (version:4.0.3) and it worked for some test file. But when I tried to run a predefined template, texmaker can't generate the changed pdf (it shows the old pdf). So I checked out the log and found an error

```
Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported.

)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.sty
****************************************
* Local config file subfigure.cfg used *
****************************************
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfigure/subfigure.cfg))
(./booktabs.sty) (./rotating.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)) (./listings.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/lstmisc.sty

***
*** This file requires `listings.sty' version 1.5.
*** You have a serious problem, so I'm exiting ...
***
```

`texlive-latex-recommended` and `texlive-latex-extra` both packages are already installed. Also  `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/listings/listings.sty` file is available.

System:

```
Ubuntu 13.10 64bit
```

What is the problem? What am I missing?

Comment: What version is your `listings.sty`? Does running `pdflatex` on the file directly work?

Comment: @bombcar Thanks for quick reply. listings.sty version is 1.5 [\def\fileversion{1.5} from file], and pdflatex file.tex is showing the same error.

Comment: I think its subfigure.sty problem. Is it?

Comment: Why is it loading listings from current dir? Along with booktabs and rotating. That lstmisc is probably not right for the local listings version.

Comment: @daleif You are right, I found a local listing.sty. Which version is 1.4(older). Removing this file works for me. Please post the comment as answer. I will mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While debugging, the log file is always a good place to look if you cannot find obvious errors in the code.

One thing to be suspicious about is packages loaded from other places than the latex dist. Double check those.

In this case a stray listings.sty was a problem

Answer (score 0):

you should use `\usepackage{listings}` in your permeable file. If you are already using it, you need to download the new version of the listings.sty from CTAN:listings and replace it with the old one.